# PREENCHER MATRIZ COM VALORES ALEATÓRIOS EM PYTHON

Tags: python

Preciso criar uma matriz de valores aleatórios, estava pensando em usar o random mas estou tendo dificuldade em adicionar esses dados à matriz; eu já tenho definido que é uma matriz 3x3. Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor?

Tentei assim e fiz outra tentativa com o numpy também, porém sem sucesso:

```
import random

matrix = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

for l in range(0,3):
    num = random.randint(0, 100)
    matrix[l].append(num)
    for c in range(0, 3):
        matrix[c].append(num)

for l in range(0, 3):
    for c in range(0, 3):
        print(f'[{matrix[l][c]:^5}]', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: A sua ideia com `random` faz total sentido. Qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Então eu criei uma variável para receber esses valores aleatórios e adiciona - los na matriz, com o .append(). Porém ele da erro e não adiciona, estou tendo um problema de lógica, eu acho.

Comment: Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar este código?

Comment: Claro, um momento

Comment: Ingred, se você já possui uma matriz 3x3 composta por zeros, o `append` irá adicionar valores na lista, mantendo os zeros.

Comment: Ah sim, agora ele deu! Porém, está repetindo muitos números. Sabe se é comum do random? Ou tem como gerar sem repetição?

Comment: Essa está sendo a saída:                                                                                               [ 97  ][ 97  ][ 46  ]
[ 97  ][ 46  ][ 46  ]
[ 97  ][ 46  ][ 53  ]
Ele repete os valores na primeira coluna

Comment: Ingred almeida veja esse código: https://ideone.com/mtkI8U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos manipular matrizes de diversas formas. Uma das mais interessantes é utilizando o biblioteca [numpy](https://numpy.org/). Esta biblioteca possui diversos métodos especializados em matrizes.

Pois bem uma das forma que podes resolver tal questão é:

1. Sortear de forma aleatória os valores que serão montados na matriz;
2. Exibir de forma agradável a matriz montada.

Como percebi - pelos seus comentários - que você deseja implementar uma matriz sem valores repetidos, sugiro utilizar o método **[sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)** da biblioteca **[random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)**.

Uma das forma que podemos implementar o código é:

```
import numpy as np
from random import sample

numeros = sample(range(1, 100 + 1), 9)
print(np.array([numeros[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(numeros), 3)]))
```

Observe que **números** é um vetor formado por **9** valores sorteados, de forma não repetida, a partir do **range(1, 100 + 1)**.

O método que garante a não repetição de valores sorteados é o método **[sample](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample)** da biblioteca **[random](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html)**.

**Por que serão sorteados 9 valores?**

Como você está querendo uma matriz **3 x 3**, isso implica que o total de elementos da referida matriz é **3 x 3 = 9**.

Então o que este código faz basicamente é:

1. Monta um vetor com 9 elementos sorteados e sem repetições;
2. Organiza visualmente a distribuição dos elementos sorteados em uma matriz **3 x 3**.

Desta forma a matriz gerada será exibida de forma mais agradável.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Vou testar aqui com numpy

Comment: Onde está o comando para não repetir? Não consegui localizar e entender

Comment: @ingred almeida, O comando que restringe a repetição é o método `sample`. Este método sorteia os valores sem repetições no range especificado. Outra coisa, se você não tiver a biblioteca instalada, terá que instalar.

Comment: Tenho instalada sim, obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

A lista `valores` tem uma lista com os numero aleatorios a serem gerados. O random gera valores no intervalo 0 ate a quantidade de numeros em `valores`, e ao ser gerado o o indice do valor ele é removido da lista, para impedir que se repita novamente.

```
import random
import numpy as np

matrix = []
valores =  list(np.arange(100))

for l in range(0,3):
    subMatriz= []
    
    for c in range(0, 3):
      i = random.randint(0, len(valores)-1)
      num = valores[i]
      valores.pop(i)
      subMatriz.append(num)
    matrix.append(subMatriz)

for l in range(0, 3):
    for c in range(0, 3):
        print(f'[{matrix[l][c]:^5}]', end='')
    print()
```

Comment: Entendi! Obrigada!